# TFS 2015 running cucumber selenium in a build

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, tfs-2015

I'm trying to run a set of cucumber selenium tests as part of a build in TFS2015, but it doesn't appear to be running them at all. I only get a timeout error. What I can conclude is that it is having difficulty starting up the browsers. I suspect that it is not running them properly from the script. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

We include Selenium tests in our feature test build by wrapping each Selenium test with MSTest and/or CodedUI attributes which works perfectly.  You do have to make sure the build/test agent is configured to run in Interactive mode otherwise the test run won't have access to the desktop to automate the browser.

http://donovanbrown.com/post/2015/08/28/auto-start-build-agent-in-interactive-mode

We don't use Cucumber however so that may be the issue for you, not sure.